# HTTP cache headers with .htaccess

Tags: caching, http-headers, browser-cache

I am trying to configure my .htaccess file to set the cache time. Tryied every possible configuration but nothing works!

This is what is written in my HTML:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=2592000, public" />
 <!--        
 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="mon, 24 sep 2012 14:30:00 GMT">
  -->
```

and this is what written in my .htaccess file:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A3600
```

However, when I refresh inclusind cache clear (ctrl+F5) in firefox, my firebug NET panel says that the cache expires at the same second I have accessed the file ( and not in the future, as I want it to be).

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 51):

I advise you to use headers mod. You can activate it (if disabled) with this command :

> a2enmod headers

Here is a simple code example that works:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

max-age is cached time in seconds.

Comment: seems that mod_headers.c is turned off. I'll have to send a request to open to the sysadmin. Why is mod_headers.c preffered over mod_expires.c?

Comment: Ok, seem to figure something out... Very strange, but see,s that A3720 means a zero. Thus, if I want an expiration of 10min, I have to wrote 3720+600 i.e 4320. This explains why "A3600" did not work. However, does anyone knows why is the zero line is 3720?!?