# Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers

Tags: php, html, http, caching, http-headers

I just finished a website that I designated and submitted it to google insights 
http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
for performance reviews, and this is the result I got. [image]

It says, I need to set expiry date or a maximum age in the the HTTP headers, but I don't know how it is possible to set expiry date for anything other than cookies/sessions.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Generally that is done using the .htaccess file on your host. Here is an example cut and pasted from [HTTP cache headers with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498017/http-cache-headers-with-htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

If delivering materials from a PHP shell you could use PHP to create the header in which case you would refer to the HTTP protocal outlined here section 14.9 Cache-Control http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

```
<?php
/* This file is a wrapper, */

header( 'Cache-Control: max-age=604800' );
/* now get and send images */
?>
```

I consider the .htaccess the easier of the two methods.

Comment: I found this .htaccess script to be very helpful https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/tree/master/dist