# how to add cache-control and expires value in html page

Tags: html, meta-tags, http-equiv

Client has asked to set the caching of the html file as:

***Cache-Control: max-age=3600, private***

***Expires: time of day in one hour***

I tried looking for a number of ways and came across only for cache-control:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private; max-age=3600" />
```

How to add "expires" header here? I read an article which states that if cache-control is set with max-age, then expires header does not matter.

Can anyone please help me in adding these meta tags in html file? Also how to update expires header with expiry date of 1 hour and update it accordingly.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use .htaccess. Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498017/http-cache-headers-with-htaccess